# Trying to mirror my website with wget, but nofollow attribute is found , and I cannot download anything more than index.html

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, wget, mirroring

I am running a wordpress site on a Ubuntu 20.04 based LEMP server.
I have the pagespeed plugin enabled, and in order to force it to cache my website, I am using wget from a different box to mirror the site. However, when using wget from a 2nd box, It stops downloading at the first page (index.html), with the error

> nofollow attribute found in /tmp/ramdisk/www.example.com/index.html. Will
> not follow any links on this page
> Below is the wget command I am using and the return results:

```
wget -m -p -E -k -P /tmp/ramdisk/ https://www.example.com
--2022-05-17 16:41:40--  https://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 1**.2*.1**.*
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|1**.2*.1**.*|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/ramdisk/www.example.com/index.html’

www.example.com/index.html                                     [   <=>                                                                                                                       ] 130.71K   210KB/s    in 0.6s

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2022-05-17 16:41:42 (210 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/ramdisk/www.example.com/index.html’ saved [133848]

nofollow attribute found in /tmp/ramdisk/www.example.com/index.html. Will not follow any links on this page
FINISHED --2022-05-17 16:41:42--
Total wall clock time: 2.0s
Downloaded: 1 files, 131K in 0.6s (210 KB/s)
Converting links in /tmp/ramdisk/www.example.com/index.html... 135.
42-93
Converted links in 1 files in 0.004 seconds.
```

How can I go about finding the nofollow attributes and removing them so wget will fully download my website?

Answer (score 2):

As [documented here](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html#How_can_I_make_Wget_ignore_the_robots.txt_file.2Fno-follow_attribute.3F) you can tell wget to ignore the no-follow attribute by adding the parameter `-e robots=off`

Comment: But a few days ago, i didnt have to implement this in wget. So what did i change on my server that created the no follow links?

Comment: How could we know?

Comment: that exactly what im asking. how coupd we know actually? is there a way tosearch forthose links in my wordpress directory or something?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

I had to log into my wordpress installation via the web interface, and go to `Settings>Reading>Search engine visibility`, then on that page I had to uncheck the

> Discourage search engines from indexing this site It is up to search
> engines to honor this request.

option. After I unchecked that, I could successfully mirror my site using the wget command `wget -m -p -E -k -P /tmp/ramdisk/ https://www.example.com`.

See the screenshot below for more info.
[image: Wordpress - Search Engine Visibility - Discourage Search Engines from Indexing this site]